# Do you know any apps in iOS app store that is done via MGWT+phonegap?

Tags: iphone, mobile, mgwt

Since we have a background in GWT coding and because it is easier to switch to MGWT from GWT we are considering to do long term mobile projects using MGWT. Are there any community behind MGWT supporting it or only one person? Do you know any apps in iOS app store that is done via MGWT+phonegap? Any mobile sites live that are done via MGWT?

Answer (score 1):

We have created a B2B App with mgwt. "d.3 smart mobile" is a frontend for our companies document management system.

iOS:
https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/d.3-mobile/id391833193?mt=8

Android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dvelop.mobile.d3mobile.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5kdmVsb3AubW9iaWxlLmQzbW9iaWxlLmFuZHJvaWQiXQ..

We had only a few bugs with iOS. The most of them, because of the iOS 6 update. These bugs were in apache cordova, not mgwt.

*Update:
With Android there were more issues within the browser (internal webview is used by cordova). Many of these bugs are workarrounded in MGWT, so that you don't have to care about. But for Android in generl you have to know lots of browser bugs, if you plan to write HTML5 Websites / Apps, especially for Android Devices newer than 2.3 and older than 4.1*

There is a usergroup https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mgwt

The community is rapidly growing.

MGWT is some kind of small widget framework with built-in animationhandler. There are many bugfixes within MGWT, that will reduce the need of special mobile CSS knowledge.

The browsers version of d.3 mobile is:
http://mobiledemo.d-velop.de:8080/mobile110

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Kurka is the one leading the MGWT community which is pretty active. He is also part of the [Google team behind the GWT project](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mgwt/SKcQp408RDg) and a [pretty active member of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201251/daniel-kurka)

Now, on commercial apps. Here is the list of all the successful PhoneGap apps most of which are done using GWT/MGWT:

http://phonegap.com/app/

So if you are worried you are the only one doing mobile with **GWT/MGWT**, the answer is; No, there are plenty of us out there doing the same, sharing and supporting others so don't lose you sleep because of this.